# Detecting UIView modification

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I need to detect from the application delegate that the main UIView(the view that the user is actually watching) has changed.

1. His there an iOS notification for that ?
2. If not, i can execute a function from a timer...but how to check that the main view (the view that the user is actually watching) has changed ?

-Fred

Comment: @user31 - what do you mean by changed - like its frame changed, subviews were added or removed from it, or something else?

Comment: What i mean by "changed": My application is composed of a tabbarcontroller + navControllers for each tabbar... Each NavigationController is composed of ViewControllers... I would like to detect from my timer code that the currentView (the user is watching) has been modified from the last timer tick ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be generic you can try using notifications.

In any UIView you want to signal its change "disappearance" you can add your notification in the dealloc method

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
}
```

and in the code that is responding to the change you can listen for the "ViewChanged" notification. You can do this with this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewChanged) name:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];

-(void)viewChanged{
 // do what ever you want after the view has changed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in fact i would like to avoid to modify each view to add this modification...and if my application is using third party library, it is not possible for me to add this notification. It is why i wanted to use a timer that analyse the change between 2 ticks...

Answer (score 0):

You should swizzle your selector for UIViewController class. Like you can swizzle for viewWillAppear to your created customViewWillAppear. So, when application will generate call for viewWillAppear, your swizzled method(customViewWillAppear) will get called. So, you can identify that, user has changed the screen.

Do not forget to call actual method to execute the stuff which are written in viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score -1):

The only way a view can change is if your app changes it at some level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...But what i want to do... I would like to add a class in any XCode project and this class is making an action if she is detecting that a view has changed (without any knowledge of project classes). My idea was to include a timer in this additional class that check if the current displayed view has changed... Hope this description is more clear for you yet.